# PHP Timed event

Tags: php, timedelay

I am using Ratchet PHP with my project and I want to trigger a function 30 seconds after a certain event happened, inside my socket server file. The socket accepts multiple connections and I want when more than 10 users join a room, to trigger an event in 30 seconds.

I cannot use sleep because it would cause the socket to be inactive for 30 seconds.

The only thing that I have in mind would be to use cURL to open another dynamic file and put a sleep event of 30 seconds in there and then trigger the code from there, but that won't be precise because sometimes, depending on server load it could take 1-2 seconds for the file called through cURL to be executed.

I cannot rely on clientside timer either, because of security.

What other options are available? 
I am basically looking for an alternative in PHP for Javascript's "setTimeout" function.

Comment: Do an internal subrequest, hand over the desired execution time and detach from it. That subrequest is handled by a script that waits until the desired time is reached. Using the `ignore_user_abort()` function you can ignore that your calling script detaches right after the request. Not sure actually if that is possible using `cURL`, but certainly it is if you open a socket and make a raw http request.

Comment: Something that can be direct compared to javascipts `setInterval()` function is not possible in php due to its non-threading character.